# How i can use circular spinning progress bar in my async task class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I want to use spinning progress bar in asynctask class. Below is my asynctask class code.

Before i use progress dialog which works properly.

```
public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Object> {


    Context c;
    String urlAddress;
    RecyclerView rv;
public Downloader(Context c, String urlAddress, RecyclerView rv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
    this.rv = rv;
    }


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    return this.downloadData();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object data) {
    super.onPostExecute(data);

    if(data.toString().startsWith("Error"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,data.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else new RssParser(c, (InputStream) data, rv).execute();
}

private Object downloadData()
{
    Object connection=Connector.connect(urlAddress);
    if(connection.toString().startsWith("Error"))
    {
        return connection.toString();
    }
```

Please comment if you want any other information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any customization for showing the progress bar in asycTask you can refer following link.
[Android custom progress indicator while doing AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085874/android-custom-progress-indicator-while-doing-asynctask)

Answer (score 0):

For my projects somtimes I use this method:

I attached ProgressBar into my layout, but I did it invisible.
And in code I write this steps:

`private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {`

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

       ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

            //My code
            }




@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {

    //My code

    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);



}
```

`}`

So, I "turn on" ProgressBar in `doInBackground` and "turn off" it in `onPostExecute`

Comment: it not works bro it give me error, i use progressbar in 2 fragments with same id.